# How do I prevent an user from accessing another user's profile?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller method called **UserSignIn** that's used to authenticate a user. The "Candidate" parameter is a model that contains fields including the contact's email address and password.

The model also contains fields "AgencyID" and "ContactID". These are used so that I know which database to connect to (AgencyID) and which contact record to get (ContactID). The user signing in is a contact at an agency.

```
[HttpPost()]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> UserSignIn(Candidate can)
{
    bool is_err = false;
    string err = string.Empty;
    Candidate c_signed_in = new Candidate();

    // check data
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(can.Email))
    {
        is_err = true;
        err += "<li>Missing email address.</li>";
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(can.AccountPassword))
    {
        is_err = true;
        err += "<li>Missing password.</li>";
    }

    // get candidate
    if (ModelState.IsValid && !is_err)
    {
        c_signed_in = await Repository.GetCandidate(can.AgencyID, 0, can.Email.ToLower(), can.AccountPassword, hostingEnv.WebRootPath);
        if (c_signed_in.ContactID == 0)
        {
            is_err = true;
            err += "<li>No account found. Check your credentials.</li>";
        }
    }

    // check model state
    if (!ModelState.IsValid || is_err)
    {
        Candidate c_current = await Repository.GetBlankCandidate(can, false);
        c_current.IsModeSignIn = true;
        if (is_err)
            c_current.ErrsSignIn = "<ul class=\"text-danger\">" + err + "</ul>";
        return View("Agency", c_current);
    }

    // create claims
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        //new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, c_signed_in.FirstName + gFunc.SPACE + c_signed_in.FamilyName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, c_signed_in.ContactID.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, c_signed_in.Email)
    };

    // create identity
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // cookie or local

    // create principal
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

    // sign-in
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme: CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal: principal);

    // add to log
    gFunc.AddLogEntry("SignIn Candidate: " + c_signed_in.FirstName + gFunc.SPACE + c_signed_in.FamilyName + " - " + c_signed_in.Email);

    // fini
    return RedirectToAction("Profile", new { agencyID = c_signed_in.AgencyID, contactID = c_signed_in.ContactID });
}
```

On success, this method redirects to a method called "Profile" that displays the user's profile.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> Profile(int agencyID, int contactID)
{
    Candidate can = await Repository.GetCandidate(agencyID, contactID, string.Empty, string.Empty, hostingEnv.WebRootPath);
    if (can.ContactID == 0)
    {
        int id = agencyID;
        return RedirectToAction("Agency", new { agencyID = id });
    }
    return View("Profile", can);
}
```

My URL is now "/Home/Profile?agencyID=5809&contactID=19492

However, I can now just change the contactID in the URL and now I'm on another user's profile without being authorized.

How do I avoid this? Obviously I can't include the password as a parameter in the **Profile** method because it would simply be visible in the URL. What approach should I be taking?

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

Thanks to all for your comments. Camilo Terevinto's answer solved my problem.

I added the info I needed to the claims in the **UserSignIn** method and removed the parameters in the **Profile** method, where I can retrieve the info I need from the active user. Now I can ensure that only the authorized user can reach the "Profile" controller method.

The only thing I had to change was the direct int cast. My compiler didn't like it, so I just change it to use a parse instead:

```
    int agency_id = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
    int contact_id = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid).Value);
```

Comment: Instead of receiving agencyID and contactID through parameters, take them from the current logged-in user

Comment: Why do you need to include the `contactID` in the url (instead of just getting the current users ID if you only want the user to see their profile)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I guess OP is unaware of that feature. (Getting "current user's ID")

Comment: I need the agencyID and contactID parameters so that I can retrieve the correct info from the right database. and I have many actions that need to redirect to "Profile".

Comment: You need those values, but not as parameters. You can use the `User` property to get those values without getting them from the URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add *agencyID* and *contactID* to Claims:

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, c_signed_in.ContactID.ToString()),
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, c_signed_in.Email),
new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,c_signed_in.agencyID.ToString())
```

In controller you can obtain it from logged user data:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> Profile()
{
    int agencyID = (int)User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
    int contactID = (int) User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid).Value

    Candidate can = await Repository.GetCandidate(agencyID, contactID, string.Empty, string.Empty, hostingEnv.WebRootPath);
    if (can.ContactID == 0)
    {
        int id = agencyID;
        return RedirectToAction("Agency", new { agencyID = id });
    }

    return View("Profile", can);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Camilo so much for your time and effort. Your answer gave me the info and understanding I needed. I can remove the parameters and also ensure that only the authorized user can reach the "Profile" controller method.